# prevent jquery conflict in wordpress customizr theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

I have this responsive tab plugin:
https://github.com/sathomas/responsive-tabs

It uses folder like tabs on larger screens, and a great button navigation on smaller screens.

It works great here (standard html site):
https://www.lifeleap.org/tabtest/

I also got it to work in our WordPress theme here:
https://www.lifeleap.org/test-site/

But in WordPress, I can only get it to work if I put the jquery.js script after the markup for the tabs and right before the script responsive-tabs.js

The issue is that jquery.js is already loading in head or WordPress by theme, so it's being loaded twice.

The tab plugin uses jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.

WordPress Customizr theme uses jQuery v1.11.1

Any suggestions on how to prevent having to load jquery.js twice?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the js for responsive-tabs.js

```
window.log=function(){log.history=log.history||[];log.history.push(arguments);if(this.console){console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}};

/*!
 * jQuery plug-in to turn bootstrap tabbed navigation into responsive tabbed navigation
 * Original author: @stephen_thomas
 * Plugin Boilerplate: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/
 * Additional Boilerplate: http://f6design.com/journal/2012/05/06/a-jquery-plugin-boilerplate/
 * Comments from boilerplate sources retained
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */


// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety 
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins 
// that are not closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global 
    // variable in ECMAScript 3 and is mutable (i.e. it can 
    // be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really 
    // being passed in so we can ensure that its value is 
    // truly undefined. In ES5, undefined can no longer be 
    // modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local 
    // variables rather than as globals, because this (slightly) 
    // quickens the resolution process and can be more 
    // efficiently minified (especially when both are 
    // regularly referenced in your plugin).


    // From http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/
    //
    // Strict Mode is a new feature in ECMAScript 5 that allows you to
    // place a program, or a function, in a "strict" operating context.
    // This strict context prevents certain actions from being taken
    // and throws more exceptions (generally providing the user with
    // more information and a tapered-down coding experience).
    //
    // Since ECMAScript 5 is backwards-compatible with ECMAScript 3,
    // all of the "features" that were in ECMAScript 3 that were
    // "deprecated" are just disabled (or throw errors) in strict
    // mode, instead.
    //
    // Strict mode helps out in a couple ways:
    //
    //  *  It catches some common coding bloopers, throwing exceptions.
    //  *  It prevents, or throws errors, when relatively "unsafe"
    //     actions are taken (such as gaining access to the global object).
    //  *  It disables features that are confusing or poorly thought out.

    "use strict";

    var pluginName = 'responsiveTabs';

    // The plug-in itself is implemented as an object. Here's the
    // constructor function

    function Plugin(element, options) {

        // Members
        var el = element,      // DOM version of element
           $el = $(element),   // jQuery version of element
           windowSize;         // last measured window size

        // Extend default options with those supplied by user.
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        // Slide the tab itself (not the content)
        function slideTab($tabEl, inOrOut, leftOrRight) {

            // grab the current values for styles we might change
            var oldStyles = {
                    "margin-left": $tabEl.css('margin-left'),
                    "opacity":     $tabEl.css('opacity'),
                    "position":    $tabEl.css('position')
                },
                startAnimation = {},
                endAnimation = {};

            // if the tab is going away, absolute position it so the
            // replacement tab will appear in its place
            if (inOrOut === 'out') {
                $tabEl.css('position', 'absolute');
                // define where the animation should end
                endAnimation["opacity"]     = 0;
                endAnimation["margin-left"] = $(window).width();
                if (leftOrRight === 'left') { endAnimation["margin-left"] *= -1; }

            // if the tab is coming into view, position it where it can
            // start its animation and set it up to fade in
            } else if (inOrOut === 'in') {
                startAnimation["opacity"]     = 0;
                startAnimation["margin-left"] = $(window).width();
                if (leftOrRight === 'left') { startAnimation["margin-left"] *= -1; }
                $tabEl.css(startAnimation);
                // ensure the tab will be visible as it moves in
                $tabEl.show();
                // end up with the modified styles restored
                endAnimation["opacity"]     = oldStyles["opacity"];
                endAnimation["margin-left"] = oldStyles["margin-left"];
            }

            // do the animation
            $tabEl.animate(
                endAnimation,
                options.slideTime,
                function() {

                    // if the tab has gone away, hide it in the conventional
                    // way and restore the properties that we animated
                    if (inOrOut === 'out') {
                        $tabEl.hide();
                        $tabEl.css(oldStyles);
                    }
                }
            );
       }

        // Set the small screen (responsive) style for tabbable naviation.
        function setSmallStyle() {

            $(".nav-tabs > li",$el).css("text-align", "center");
            $(".nav-tabs > li:not(.active)",$el).hide();
            $("<a class='right tab-control'>&rsaquo;</a>").appendTo($(".nav-tabs li:not(:last-child)",$el))
              .each(function(i){
                var thisLi  = $(this).parents("ul").first().children("li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")"),
                    thisTab = $(thisLi).children("a[href]"),
                    nextLi  = $(this).parents("ul").first().children("li:nth-child("+(i+2)+")"),
                    nextTab = $(nextLi).children("a[href]");
                $(this).click(function() {
                    slideTab(thisLi, "out", "left" );
                    slideTab(nextLi, "in",  "right");
                    $(nextTab).tab('show');
                });
            });
            $("<a class='left tab-control'>&lsaquo;</a>").prependTo($(".nav-tabs li:not(:first-child)",$el))
              .each(function(i){
                var thisLi = $(this).parents("ul").first().children("li:nth-child("+(i+2)+")"),
                    thisTab = $(thisLi).children("a[href]"),
                    prevLi = $(this).parents("ul").first().children("li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")"),
                    prevTab = $(prevLi).children("a[href]");
                $(this).click(function() {
                    slideTab(thisLi, "out", "right");
                    slideTab(prevLi, "in", "left");
                    $(prevTab).tab('show');
                });
            });
            $(".nav-tabs li:first-child",$el).prepend("<span class='left tab-control-spacer'> </span>");
            $(".nav-tabs2 li:last-child",$el).append("<span class='right tab-control-spacer'> </span>");
        }

        // Set the large screen version of tabbable navigation;
        // this is just the bootstrap default, so all we need to do is
        // to undo any potential changes we made for a small screen
        // style.

        function setLargeStyle() {

            $(".nav-tabs > li",$el).css("text-align", "left");
            $(".nav-tabs > li:not(.active)",$el).show();
            $(".tab-control",$el).remove();
            $(".tab-control-spacer",$el).remove();

        }

        function windowResized() {

            // Although this isn't strictly necessary, let's monitor the
            // window size so we can detect when it crosses the threshold
            // that triggers re-styling. Not likely a big deal for actual
            // users, but we include the functionality for the geeks that
            // like to look at responsive web sites and mess around with
            // browser window widths.
            //
            // We're not bothering with debouncing the window resize 
            // event since we only care when a breakpoint is crossed.
            // Ignoring the other resizes effectively serves as a
            // debouncer.

            var newWidth = $('body').width();
            if ( (windowSize > options.maxSmallWidth) && 
                 (newWidth <= options.maxSmallWidth) )  {

                setSmallStyle();

            } else if ( (windowSize <= options.maxSmallWidth) && 
                        (newWidth > options.maxSmallWidth) ) {

                setLargeStyle();

            }
            windowSize = newWidth;
        }

        // Initialize plugin.
        function init() {
            // keep track of the window size so we can tell when it crosses a breakpoint
            windowSize = $('body').width();

            // default is large window styling; adjust if appropriate
            if (windowSize <= options.maxSmallWidth) {
                setSmallStyle();
            }

            // track window size changes to look for breakpoints
            $(window).on('resize', windowResized);

            hook('onInit');

        }

        // Get/set a plugin option.
        // Get usage: $('#el').demoplugin('option', 'key');
        // Set usage: $('#el').demoplugin('option', 'key', value);

        function option (key, val) {
            if (val) {
                options[key] = val;
            } else {
                return options[key];
            }
        }

        // Destroy plugin.
        // Usage: $('#el').demoplugin('destroy');

        function destroy() {
            // Clean up by removing the event handlers we've added
            $(window).off('resize', windowResized);

            // restore styles and DOM
            setLargeStyle();

            // Iterate over each matching element.
            $el.each(function() {
                var el = this,
                   $el = $(this);

                hook('onDestroy');

                // Remove Plugin instance from the element.
                $el.removeData('plugin_' + pluginName);
            });
        }

        // Callback hooks.
        // Usage: In the defaults object specify a callback function:
        // hookName: function() {}
        // Then somewhere in the plugin trigger the callback:
        // hook('hookName');

        function hook(hookName) {
            if (options[hookName] !== undefined) {
                // Call the user defined function.
                // Scope is set to the jQuery element we are operating on.
                options[hookName].call(el);
            }
        }

        // Initialize the plugin instance.
        init();

        // Expose methods of Plugin we wish to be public.
        return {
            option: option,
            destroy: destroy
        };
    }

    // Build the plugin here 

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {

        // If the first parameter is a string, treat this as a call to
        // a public method. The first parameter is the method name and
        // following parameters are arguments for the method.

        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
            var methodName = arguments[0];
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            var returnVal;
            this.each(function() {
                // Check that the element has a plugin instance, and that
                // the requested public method exists.
                if ( $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName) && 
                     typeof $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)[methodName] === 'function' ) {
                    // Call the method of the Plugin instance, and Pass it
                    // the supplied arguments.
                    returnVal = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)[methodName].apply(this, args);
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Method ' +  methodName + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName);
                }
            });
            if (returnVal !== undefined){
                // If the method returned a value, return the value.
                return returnVal;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, returning 'this' preserves chainability.
                return this;
            }

        // If the first parameter is an object (options), or was omitted,
        // instantiate a new instance of the plugin.

        } else if (typeof options === "object" || !options) {

            return this.each(function() {
                // Only allow the plugin to be instantiated once.
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    // Pass options to Plugin constructor, and store Plugin
                    // instance in the elements jQuery data object.
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // Default plugin options.
    // Options can be overwritten when initializing plugin, by
    // passing an object literal, or after initialization:
    // $('#el').responsiveTabs('option', 'key', value);
    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        maxSmallWidth: 767,   // biggest screen size for which we use "small" configuration
        slideTime: 500,       // milliseconds to slide from one tab to another
        onInit: function() {},
        onDestroy: function() {}
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabbable.responsive").responsiveTabs(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Joomla! extension developer but don't know a lot about WP extensions. I give you a path and you think it over.
One of the best solutions for a case like this in Joomla! is overriding the extension output. It always works.
The idea is removing the output i.e. inserting the library in the head.

We do this after checking the extensions user interface because providing an option for loading/don't loading the jQuery library is common in Joomla! extension development.

Comment: Amin  - thank you for the insight. I could be wrong, but I'm guessing the issue with this plugin is either something in the posted code needs to be upgraded for jQuery v1.11.1. Or, if the jQuery v1.7.1 is not included on the page, the responsive-tabs.js is loading in the wrong place. Not sure about overriding extension output - I will check into this.